# LWC - NavigationMixin: Show A List Of Record Types (Closed)

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, button, navigationmixin.navigate

Normally, when we create new record and if that record has different record types, a pop-up will show up with a list of record types when user click create new.

I'm trying to aim that with NavigationMixin but it only show a window to create new one.

Is there anyway to fetch a list of records type and display it for user to choose. After done choosing, user will land on that record type page layout?

My code:

JavaScript:

```
navigateToCreateNewRecord() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Equipment__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        })
    }
```

Thank you guys so much,
Pam.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're aiming at: If I'm on a record detail page, the layout used to render the page will depend on the RecordType of the respective object. Do you need a LWC that breaks out of this behaviour? That being said, please add your existing code to your question. StackExchange is not a website to search for people to do free coding services; it is for specific answers for specific questions. It would also clarify your question.

Comment: Hi @FelixvanHove,

Thank you so much for answering my question.

This evening I made an edit but somehow StackExchange did not respond to it. I will be back and edit for more information later.

Comment: Hi @FelixvanHove, I edited my question and included code snippet. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: What happens now when you navigate to the new page?  Why don't you override the new button? Or can't you do this for all users?

Comment: Hi @NickCook, thank you for your comment

I'm not sure what you are mentioning about but for now, when user hit 'New' in the Org, a list of records type will show up. 

Right now with NavigationMixin, it only land on the default new page.

I would like to have the same action that will show a list of records type of that object when user hits the button with NavigationMixin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the object that you are passing, an optional parameter called **state** can be added where you can pass additional data like **defaultFieldValues**, **useRecordTypeCheck** etc.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'Equipment__c',
            actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
            useRecordTypeCheck: 'true'
        }
    })
```

Adding this will enable record type selection before showing the record creation page. To know more about navigation in LWC you can check this link: [LWC Navigation](https://sfwiseguys.wordpress.com/2020/11/15/lwc-navigation/), it has some good examples.

Comment: Hi @Chandrashekaran, thank you so much for solution. It worked!

I also found a way to hard code the record type list but yours is much better.